# action cable not working on deployement with docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker-compose, actioncable

I've a issue with my Ruby on rails 5 app.
In developpement everything is working but when i deploy using docker on my server (ubuntu 16 LTS), action cable is not working.

I followed these tutos:

- https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/dockerize-a-rails-5-postgres-redis-sidekiq-action-cable-app-with-docker-compose
- https://www.spannersoftware.com/rails-5-puma-nginx-actioncable/

Here are my files:

- docker-compose.yml

  ```
  version: '3'
  services:
    db:
      image: postgres:9.6
      environment:
        - ACIM_DATABASE_PASSWORD=ACIM_2018
      volumes:
        - 'db:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
      env_file:
        - '.env'
      expose:
        - '5432'
      ports:
        - "7000:5432"
    nginx: 
      image: nginx:latest
      container_name: production_nginx
      volumes:
        - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - public-content:/var/www/acim/public
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
      links:
      - web

    # maildev:
    #   image: djfarrelly/maildev
    #   ports:
    #     - "2000:80"

    redis:
      image: redis
      command: redis-server
      volumes:
        - 'redis:/data'
      ports:
        - "6379"

    sidekiq:
      build: .
      #command: sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
      command: bundle exec sidekiq
      volumes:
        - .:/ACIM
      links:
        - db
        - redis
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
      env_file:
        - '.env'
    web:
      build: .
      command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
      volumes:
        - bundle_cache:/bundle
        - public-content:/var/www/acim/public
        - .:/ACIM
      ports:
        - "5000:3000"
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
      env_file:
        - '.env'

    cable:
      depends_on:
        - 'redis'
      build: .
      command: puma -p 28080 cable/config.ru
      ports:
        - '28080:28080'
      volumes:
        - '.:/ACIM'
      env_file:
        - '.env'

  volumes:
    bundle_cache:
    redis:
    db:
    public-content:
  ```
- My Dockerfile

  ```
  FROM ruby:2.5.1

  # Install dependencies
  RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

  ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/acim/public
  RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT
  RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/log
  RUN rm -rf /var/www/acim/public/tmp/pids/server.pid

  # Set working directory, where the commands will be ran:
  WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

  # Setting env up
  ENV RAILS_ENV='production'
  ENV RACK_ENV='production'

  # Adding gems
  COPY Gemfile Gemfile
  COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
  RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5 --without development test

  # Adding project files
  COPY . .
  RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

  EXPOSE 3000
  CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
  ```

  - My NGINX file

  ```
  user www-data;
  worker_processes 4;
  pid /run/nginx.pid;

  events {
      worker_connections 768;
      # multi_accept on;
  }

  http {

      ##
      # Basic Settings
      ##

      sendfile on;
      tcp_nopush on;
      tcp_nodelay on;
      keepalive_timeout 65;
      types_hash_max_size 2048;
      # server_tokens off;

      # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
      # server_name_in_redirect off;

      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      default_type application/octet-stream;

      ##
      # Logging Settings
      ##

      # access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      # error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

      upstream acim {
          server 192.168.99.100:5000;
      }

      server {
      listen 0.0.0.0;
      server_name 192.168.99.100;

      root /var/www/acim/publc;

      # define where Nginx should write its logs
      # access_log /var/www/acim/log/nginx.access.log;
      # error_log /var/www/acim/log/nginx.error.log;

      try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://acim;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
      }

      location /assets/ {
          expires 1y;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
          add_header ETag "";
          root /var/www/acim/public/public;
      }

      location /cable {
          proxy_pass http://192.168.99.100:28080;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }
      location /redis {
          proxy_pass http://192.168.99.100:6379;
      }

      error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
      client_max_body_size 4G;
      keepalive_timeout 10;
    }
  }
  ```
- My config/environements/production.rb

  ```
  Rails.application.configure do
    # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

    # Code is not reloaded between requests.
    config.cache_classes = true

    # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
    # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
    # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
    # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
    config.eager_load = true

    # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
    config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
    # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
    # config.require_master_key = true

    # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
    # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
    config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

    # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
    config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
    # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

    # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
    config.assets.compile = false

    # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

    # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
    # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

    # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
    # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
     config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX


    # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
    config.active_storage.service = :local

    # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
    # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
    config.action_cable.url = 'ws://192.168.99.100/cable'
    config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://192.168.99.100', /http:\/\/192.168.99.100.*/ ]

    #config.action_cable.url = [/ws:\/\/*/, /wss:\/\/*/]
    #config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]

    # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
    # config.force_ssl = true

    # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
    # when problems arise.
    config.log_level = :debug

    # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
    config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

    # Use a different cache store in production.
    # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

    # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
    # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
    # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "ACIM_#{Rails.env}"

    config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

    # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
    # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
    # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

    # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
    # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true

    # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

    # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
    config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

    # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
    # require 'syslog/logger'
    # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

    if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
      logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
      logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
      config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
    end

    # Do not dump schema after migrations.
    config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false


    # ne pas directement servir les fichiers public 
    # en utilisant ruby, mais passons par NGINX
    config.public_file_server.enabled = false
    config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
  end

  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js ^[^_]*.css *.css.erb )
  ```

Here is the output of the tab network [WS] of chrome developper tools.
[chrome developper tool-> network -> ws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwCDp.png)

Can you please help me ?
Thanks

Comment: How did you solve this problem?